# Translation Request - Grothendieck's Tohoku Paper

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

I've been learning sheaf cohomology, and was interested in reading Grothendieck's Tohoku paper. However, I don't read French.

I've done a semi-extensive google search, and the majority of links end up linking back to http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/09/grothendiecks_tohoku_paper.html, which provides a link to an English translation by Michael Barr. However, the link provided to his translation is broken.

Does anyone have a copy of this translation saved that they might be able to reupload elsewhere or email to me?

Also, I realize this might be a semi-taboo question, given Grothendieck's stated wishes on such matters, but I figured I'd ask anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could email Michael Barr for a copy..

Comment: This is just a personal observation. We used this paper as the text in a course in homological algebra. I read French, quite well. Even at that, I could have used a translator. I gave up and used Cartan and Eilenberg instead. I'd ask around and see if there might be a more accessible (in the sense of available) account of the topics that Grothendieck treated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](ftp://ftp.math.mcgill.ca/barr/pdffiles/gk.pdf) is the current link to Barr's translation (remove "pub" directory from the old rotted link).

Comment: This link no longer works. Furthermore, it seems like few (if any) links on Michael Barr's website works.

Comment: @fhyve It seems that browser ftp access isn't working at the moment, but it still works fine using an FTP program (I just tried).

Comment: can you download and send it to me ma10d010@smail.iitm.ac.in

Comment: This link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 15):

I could not get the above link to work, either from a browser or from an ftp client.

This link works, at least as of October 17, 2014:
http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/gk.pdf

Comment: Still works Feb. 13 2023.

Answer (score 1):

Another link to Professor Barr's translation of Grothendieck's Tohoku paper:

Marcia L. Barr and Michael Barr (2011) Some aspects of homological algebra
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/BarrTranslOf-GrothedieckTohoku.pdf